# How to enable PMU in WSL2?

Tags: linux, performance, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pm-utils

I am using WSL2 in Windows11 as my Linux host.
Now I want to run `perf` in this WSL2, but I failed to do that with following errors.

```
# uname -a
Linux testhost 5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Thu Oct 5 21:02:42 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# dmesg | grep -i perf
[    0.039284] Performance Events: unsupported p6 CPU model 154 no PMU driver, software events only.
[    0.204569]     Performance counters on
```

I already added following line in USRNAME/.wslconfig in Windows.

```
hardwarePerformanceCounters=true
```

And run following commands in Powershell as administrative

```
PS C:\Users\aa> wsl --update
Checking updates
Updating WSL2 subsystem to version: 2.0.14.
PS C:\Users\aa> dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart

Deploying service and management tool.
Version: 10.0.22621.1

Image version: 10.0.22621.1848

Done started one or more functions
[==========================100.0%==========================]
Done
```

But the WSL2 Linux failed to get PMU hardware.

I am not sure it is OK to post WSL2 related question here, if NOT, sorry for that.